# How to access a single css file in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am currently working witn Rails 3.1. I need to use only one css file but the problem is that when I add the

```
<link href="http://mydomain.net/assets/some.css"></link>
```

it doesn't exist. I need to get the css files from that particular css file and no other css files should be loaded.

How do I do that in Rails 3.1?

Update:

Adding this  to production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['some.css']
```

causes the following error:

```
 ** [out :: domain.net] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: domain.net] stack level too deep
 ** [out :: domain.net] (in /home/deployer/apps/domain/releases/20120410204601/app/assets/stylesheets/some.css.scss)
 ** [out :: domain.net] 
 ** [out :: domain.net] Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
 ** [out :: domain.net] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Update #2:

the filename for some.css is actually some.css.scss.

Update #3:

I just discovered the problem and it is caused by this:

https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/78

Comment: In which folder is your `some.css` ? I've tried it and it's working fine in my app.

Comment: it is in the `assets/stylesheets` folder. Take note that I am in production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are in production environment, all your assets must be precompiled, i.e. turned into static files and copied to `/public`.

In production all your individual files in `app/assets` are not directly accessible because they are not precompiled. Your individual css files are not precompiled when you run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

According to the [asset pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets):

> If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript
>   files to include, you can add them to the precompile array:

So for you, add a manifest header at the top of your css file:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 */
```

And then add in your config:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['some.css']
```

Then precompile your assets and access your css file as usual:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'some' %>
```

Edit by @Thorpe Obazee

The answer is essentially correct if only sass-rails 3.1.5 didn't have any issues. So I accepted the answer.

https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/78

Comment: This causes errors when deploying, `stack level too deep` when adding this to production.rb, `config.assets.precompile += ['some.css']`

Comment: I tested it with no troubles on my machine. This error is very large, I can't help you without more details.

Comment: Are you setting up your website on heroku?

Comment: No, I am not setting this up on heroku.

Comment: @Thorpe_Obazee Great! I saw this error when I google for that but I didn't believe this can be the cause (because there was many other plausible reasons).

Comment: Maybe it's obvious (?), but the file name referenced in the precompile assignment must be the name *after* the precompile. I.e., some.css, *not* some.css.scss.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your stylesheet to your assets folder. Then use

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "some", :media => "all" %>
```

to load your stylesheet.